# CentOS 7 Share a file on my network so anyone can download it

Tags: centos, ftp, vsftpd

I wanted to share a tar file on my server so that anyone on my network can download it. For example, I would give them a link like

```
192.168.2.2/windows.tar
```

They should be able to download it from their web browser with that link or

```
wget 192.168.2.2/windows.tar
```

does anyone have any suggestion on what package I can use to approach this. Tutorials would be even better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible packages to use -- httpd, or nginx.  Both are provided by CentOS 7.

httpd is better known as Apache Web Server, and its documentation is available by googling "centos 7 httpd"

nginx is a much smaller and lighter web server, and its documentation is available by googling "Centos 7 nginx

Either one will do a perfectly good job handling the requirements you've specified.

Hint:  You will place your "windows.tar" file into a specified server directory.  What you also want to do to prevent accessors from seeing any other content you might have in that directory is to "touch index.html" there.  This will make a zero-length file which will prevent the nginx or httpd default splash screen from displaying, and won't give away the software you are using -- which hackers want to know if they decide to target your server.

But do all of that after you've installed your preferred product.  You'll do something like this link (in your favorite web browser):  http://192.168.2.2/

What that should do is to show you the default splash screen.  At that point, once you have the splash screen visible, you can add your content to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of systems have `python` already installed. If you do then you can do the following

```
# create a directory of things to export
mkdir Export
# put your file in it
cp windows.tar Export
# use python to serve up the directory
cd Export
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

then `wget 192.168.w.w:8000/windows.tar` will get your file.

Of course this is not a full featured web service like Apache or nginx, but it has the advantage that you probably don't need to install anything.

If you want the web server to persist then `nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer &` and you probably want to remove the `nohup.out` file as it will show the requests.